# Parsleyjs Date Validation Doesn't work on Datepicker Events like Onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker, parsley.js

I have a form with date picker input field which asks for value even after the date is chosen.

note: This error doesn't come when i type the value.

[image]

```
<input data-parsley-trigger="change" name="epa_date" required type="text" class="form-control" id="single_cal1" placeholder="(YYYY/MM/DD)">
<script>
$('#single_cal1').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
              minDate: moment(),
             format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            maxDate:  moment().add(15, 'days'),
            calender_style: "picker_1"
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
        });
</script>
```

Edit Note: I have updated the script for date picker i use. 
I am using Parsleyjs for all validations.

Comment: validation is there?

Comment: Show more code, please

Comment: @CodeLove Yes, Validation is there even after the required input is filled.

Comment: To be clear, your issue is that the validation isn't triggered when the value is typed on the input? That might have something to do with the datepicker component. Can you provide a fiddle that replicates your issue and a detailed description of your issue ?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the issue w/ the bootstrap-datepicker and this fixed the issue for me: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

```
$('#datefield').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        $(this).parsley().validate();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using the [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) with [Parsley 2.0](http://parsleyjs.org), and this worked for me (thanks [@siva anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573744/siva-anand))..

```
$(function() {
    $("#yourdatefield").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        onClose: function () {
        $(this).parsley().validate();
        }
    });
```

and then in the parsley field..

```
'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i have triggered the parsley again in daterangepicker. It worked for me.

```
   <input data-parsley-trigger="change" name="epa_date" required type="text" class="form-control" id="single_cal1" placeholder="(YYYY/MM/DD)">
    <script>
    $('#single_cal1').daterangepicker({
                singleDatePicker: true,
                  minDate: moment(),
                 format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
                maxDate:  moment().add(15, 'days'),
                calender_style: "picker_1"
            }, function (start, end, label) {
                $('#single_cal1').parsley().validate();
                console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
            });
    </script>
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize parsley, add change to triggerAfterFailure, so when you pick a date or change the date, parsley will revalidate. The default for triggerAfterFailure is input.

```
$('form.parsley').parsley({
        triggerAfterFailure: 'input change'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7451), it looks like the validation has to be triggered manually on change. The following worked for me:

```
var d = $('#single_cal1');
d.daterangepicker({
  onClose: function() {
    d.validate();
  }
});
```